# Transpose a subset of columns into rows and keep remaining columns in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have data for an event registration that will be coming to me weekly in CSV a file.  I have dummied down the data for simplicity, but the basic idea is that it will look like the following:

```
Team Name1 Name2 Name3 Total
1    a     b     c     10
2    d     e     f     20
3    g     h     i     30
4    j     k     l     40
5    m     n     o     50
6    p     q     r     60
7    s     t     u     70
```

Each week for the full data set I need to be able to transpose columns Name1, Name2, and Name 3 into rows and keep all other columns the same so that it looks like the following:

```
Team Name Total
1    a    10
1    b    10
1    c    10
2    d    20
2    e    20
2    f    20
3    g    30
3    h    30
3    i    30
4    j    40
4    k    40
4    l    40
5    m    50
5    n    50
5    o    50
6    p    60
6    q    60
6    r    60
7    s    70
7    t    70
7    u    70
```

- The final format needs to be in an Excel file.
- What is the best approach for this sort of task?  Excel/VBA?  Access?
- I don't have to have the column names in the final format (I could just add those back in myself if that adds too much to the complexity).

I tried this with VBA using what I could find on the internet as I am not a VBA expert, so before I went further trying to learn VBA more thoroughly, I thought I would see what technology is most recommended and whether or not anyone has a simple solution that might work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can do this in Excel. A simple Loop can take care of what you want. I have answered a similar question quite sometime back... Will have to search for it. If I am able to then I will post back

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was Access, but if this is all you're doing, you can stay in Excel.

This can even be done without VBA--just Excel formulas using MATCH() (for the team name, returns the Excel row) and INDEX() (give it the MATCH() result and it will return NAME1, 2 or 3 or Total).

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] A friend just helped me write an awk script to create a new CSV file instead, and it was pretty simple.  I am going to go that route.